# SAS how to efficiently look up and match

Tags: join, sas, match, lookup

I have a table A of 36 columns of names. There's a name-id xwalk file, let's call it x. I need to add to table A 36 columns of IDs, using the xwalk file x.

Actual data/table sizes are provided here for efficiency consideration if needed:
my table A has 340 rows, names are all texts.
xwalk table x has 700+ rows, ids are all numeric.
each time when a column in A of names is to be matched to IDs, xwalk can be subsetted to a smaller number of potential pools. Size of such subsets range from: 9 to 140.

I suppose I can do a left join 36 times, but it seems there should be a more efficient way to do it.
any suggestions?

for simplicity, example data code for table A has 4 columns.

```
data A;
 input  name1 $1-5  name2 $7-10 name3 $12-15 name4 $17-20;
 datalines;
Harry Mary John Kate
Lee   Sam  Joel Sky
;
run;

data x;
input name $1-5 id;
datalines;
Harry 1
Marry 2
John  3
Kate  4
Sam   5
Sky   7
Joel  12
Lee  99
;
run;


data want;
input name1 $1-5  name2 $7-10 name3 $12-15 name4 $17-20 id1 id2 id3 id4;
datalines;
Harry Mary John Kate 1 2 3 4
Lee   Sam  Joel Sky 99 5 12 7
;
run;
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a combination of arrays and hash objects.Load table x into a hash table and iterate through an array of your 36 columns of names.

Comment: Can you show a small example that illustrates your issue? It's hard to understand what's a variable vs an observation from the way you've described your data. My suggestion is usually to use formats, so your xwalk table becomes a format and then apply the formats to the table.

Comment: Why not transpose the wide table and the join them?  Do you really need to retranspose it back to wide, why not just use it in the tall format instead?

Comment: You seem to be hinting at the fact that you do not want an exact match on name.  If that is true then what is your matching criteria?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hash object/array version:

```
data want;
    if _n_ = 1 then do;
        if 0 then set x;
        declare hash x(dataset:"x");
        x.DefineKey("name");
        x.DefineData("id");
        x.DefineDone();
    end;
    
    set a;
    array nms{4} $ name1-name4;
    array ids{4} id1-id4;

    do i = 1 to dim(nms);
        if x.find(key:nms{i}) = %sysrc(_sok) then ids{i} = id;
        else id = .;
    end;
    
    drop i id name;
run;
```